# Changing the collation in a single query using Linq to NHibernate

Tags: .net, sql-server, linq, nhibernate, collation

I have to use a different collation(SQL Server) in a single query in Linq to NHibernate.

Like this:
    var peoples = session.Query().Where(f=>f.Name.Contains('João', Collation.AccentInsensitive));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the NHibernate source code doesn't even contain the needed SQL keyword for this (`COLLATE`) I'd say that you need to implement it yourself. Look here: [NHibernate LINQ provider extension](http://fabiomaulo.blogspot.co.at/2010/07/nhibernate-linq-provider-extension.html)

Comment: This example use the HqlTreeBuilder.Like() existing method. Have you an example of a new keyword implementation?

Comment: My problem is append the collate to result in: SELECT * FROM Peoples WHERE Name COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS = 'João'

Comment: @PatrickCoelho You have to register a custom SQL function in a custom dialect and then call this function in the HQL builder with `treeBuilder.MethodCall`.